# Using File Descriptors in Visual Studio 2010 and Windows

Tags: c++, file, file-descriptor

I have a program in C++ which accepts some text from the user and saves it to a text file.  Here are snippets of the program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int file_descriptor;
size_t nob;

int check_file(const char* full_path) //Method to check whether a file already exists
{
    file_descriptor = open(full_path, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777); //Checking whether the file exists and saving its properties into a file descriptor
}

void write_to_file(const char* text) //Method to create a file and write the text to it
{
    time_t current = time(0); //Getting the current date and time
    char *datetime = ctime(&current); //Converting the date and time to string

    nob = write(file_descriptor, "----Session----\n\n"); //Writing text to the file through file descriptors
    nob = write(file_descriptor, "Date/Time: %s\n\n", datetime); //Writing text to the file through file descriptors
    nob = write(file_descriptor, "Text: %s", text); //Writing text to the file through file descriptors
    nob = write(file_descriptor, "\n\n\n\n"); //Writing text to the file through file descriptors
}
```

There are three main problems with this program:

1. Visual Studio is telling me that it cannot open source file `<unistd.h>` (no such file or directory).
2. Identifier `open` is undefined.
3. Identifier `write` is undefined.

How can I solve these problems please?  I am using Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 7 platform.  I would like to make use of file descriptors in my program.

Comment: This seems to be C++. Retagged it.

Comment: That's not the POSIX `write` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open` and `write` are (Unix) platform specific. The C standard way for file access is `FILE*`, `fopen` and `fwrite`.

If you stil want to use `open`/`write` you should take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z(v=vs.100).aspx. Microsoft has added support for open/write, but renamed the (non-C-standard) functions to `_open`/`_write`.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to use them in Windows?

Comment: True, but misleading.  Visual C++ ships with implementations of these functions, no need to write your own.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Thanks for pointing that out, of course you are right. I deleted my comment and updated my answer to include the _open/_write functions and a link to the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Visual C++ prefers the ISO-conformant names for these functions: [_open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx) and [_write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1570wh78.aspx).  However the POSIX names `open` and `write` work just fine.

You need to `#include <io.h>` in order to access them.

Besides this, your code is not using the `write` function correctly.  You seem to think it's another name for `printf`, POSIX disagrees.

---

This code compiles just fine in Visual C++.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int file_descriptor;
size_t nob;

int check_file(const char* full_path) //Method to check whether a file already exists
{
    return open(full_path, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777); // Checking whether the file exists and saving its properties into a file descriptor
}

void write_to_file(const char* text) // Function to write a binary time_t to a previously opened file
{
    time_t current = time(0); //Getting the current date and time

    nob = write(file_descriptor, &current, sizeof current);
}
```

If you create a `unistd.h` file that contains `#include <io.h>`, and stick it into your system include path, then you won't need any code changes whatsoever (assuming your code is POSIX-compliant to begin with).

Comment: @Alex: Yes they are.  The [old](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms235491.aspx) [names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms235320.aspx) are even forwarded to the new ones, although using the ISO names is recommended in new code.

Comment: The only way to compile this code in Windows without changes is to use Cygwin, as any other code that uses Linux system calls. Your answer suggests to change the code, by changing the function names and include files.

Comment: @Alex: You're wrong.  The compiler accepts the names `open` and `write` just fine, although you get warnings.

Comment: @AlexF Have you actually tested whether it compiles?  I just tried it with MSVC 2010, and it worked as is.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use this code under Windows without changes, try Cygwin: http://www.cygwin.com/

However, it is much better to rewrite this code using C Library FILE functions, as already suggested in another answers. This will work in any OS.

Comment: Visual C++ provides these functions, cygwin is not required.  All that's needed is to use the right header.  The rest of your answer is just repeating what others said; that's not helpful.